# Is it okay to pass my model into my view model via its constructor through MVVM practices?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, model, view

```
public class LDLTrackViewModel : RailwayViewModel {

    private LDLTrack _ldlTrack;



    public LDLTrack LDLTrack {
        get => _ldlTrack;
        set { _ldlTrack = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LDLTrack");
        }
    }

    public LDLTrackViewModel(LDLTrack ldlTrack) {
        LDLTrack = ldlTrack;  
        LineCoords = new ObservableCollection<LineCoordinates>(ldlTrack.LineCoordList);

        ZIndex = -50;

    }
```

}

My system is set up that I've filled my models with data through reading a big file. I then pass these models to various view models via their constructor (I have the same amount of view models as I do models):

```
LDLTracks = new ObservableCollection<LDLTrackViewModel>(TrainSimAllData.AllLDLTracks.Select(ldl => new LDLTrackViewModel(ldl)));
```

Where LDLTracks is a collection of LDLTrackViewModels. I then bind to this list of view models in my view. I'm wondering if this is the normal way to go about things or whether there's a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would not have an issue with the view model constructor taking an `LDLTrack` and using it to populate itself. That's a fairly tidy, well-encapsulated way of doing things.

What I wouldn't be so keen on is then exposing that model to consumers via a property - instead, I'd populate fields explicitly defined for the properties that the view model represents:

```
public class LDLTrackViewModel : RailwayViewModel {

    private readonly string _theFoo;
    private readonly int _theBar;

    public string TheFoo => _theFoo;
    public int TheBar => _theBar;

    public LDLTrackViewModel(LDLTrack ldlTrack) {
        _theFoo = ldlTrack.Foo;
        _theBar = ldlTrack.Bar;
    }
}
```

This will help to reduce coupling - the view model's job is to communicate certain information and the constructor allows the `LDLTrack` model to be one source of that information, without further binding other consumers to that type.

Comment: That makes sense - I think I remember a tutorial doing a similar thing now I think about it as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the constructor should be reserved for dependency injection. The data can be mapped in many ways. I do it like this for one of my MVVM apps

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/54830badaf876737b2b9c5bf2cd2c05e65ac0450/FreePIE.GUI/Views/Curves/CurveViewModel.cs#L32

Used like

```
    private void CreateCurvesModel()
    {
        Curves = new BindableCollection<CurveViewModel>(settingsManager.Settings.Curves.Select(c => curveModelFactory().Configure(c)));
    }
```